# How can we remove or escape garbage value like =3D or =3D&&quote while parsing mhtml or html page using jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract data from offline saved html pages using jsoup, but while parsing the html document through my java code, I'm getting some garbage value like =3D, =3d&&quote, etc. Is there any way to remove those garbage value using jsoup or any other way in java.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What you call “garbage” is actually the [quoted-printable](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045#section-6.7) encoding.  All web frameworks understand and properly decode it.  If you’re going to parse a raw HTTP response yourself, you will need to look for a Content-Transfer-Encoding header that specifies quoted-printable content, and if one is found, you’ll need to decode it yourself.